# Three Adjacent Riddles

Tags: riddle, pattern, english

When I am two
There is an
Irrelevant
Announcement
Of surprise, with uff
For I am really six or thirteen.

When the sun rises
Over this eastern shore
Hesitating briefly
Before quickly passing this small place
I watch, that is all
Walking west to where I must stop
And consider what I have crossed.

I and no other
Lost
This letter.
I watch, that is all
Til we are together
Here in our homeland.

Hint:

> If you solve one (or part of one), the rest should fall quickly, and will be obviously correct.

Hint 2:

> If I told you the number of lines in riddle 4, you could tell me the answers to each line, without seeing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These paragraphs clue:

> the three 'adjacent' **countries: CANADA, AMERICA and MEXICO**.
>
>  In each instance the last line is a definition of sorts and the other lines each represent two consecutive characters from the name (either by definition or cryptic clue-style wordplay), which when overlapped together spell out the names we seek.

**Riddle 1:**

*When I am two*

> **CA** - the two-letter country code for Canada.

*There is an*

> **AN** (there is 'an', quite literally...)

*Irrelevant*

> **NA** (not applicable)

*Announcement*

> **AD** (advertisement)

*Of surprise, with uff*

> [UFF **DA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uff_da)

*For I am really six or thirteen.*

> **CANADA** is a country of [six Haudenosaunee nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Nations_of_the_Grand_River) or, alternatively, thirteen political provinces and territories.

**Riddle 2:**

*When the sun rises*

> **AM** (a.m. - the morning, when the sun rises)

*Over this eastern shore*

> **ME** - the abbreviation for Maine, a state on the eastern shore of the US.

*Hesitating briefly*

> **ER**...

*Before quickly passing this small place*

> **RI** - the abbreviation for the smallest US state, Rhode Island.

*I watch, that is all*

> **I C** ('I see' = *I watch*)

*Walking west to where I must stop*

> **CA** - the abbreviation for California, on the west coast of the US.

*And consider what I have crossed.*

> This whole set of clues has described a passage across the United States of **AMERICA**!

**Riddle 3:**

*I and no other*

> **ME**

*Lost*

> **EX**

*This letter.*

> **XI** - a letter of the Greek alphabet.

*I watch, that is all*

> **I C** ('I see' = *I watch*)

*Til we are together*

> **CO** - a prefix meaning 'together'

*Here in our homeland.*

> Together this all clues the country of **MEXICO**, whose national motto is '*La Patria Es Primero*', meaning 'The *Homeland* is First'.

Comment: And yes, I was finally able to work this one out once I had solved its [sister puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115509/three-more-adjacent-riddles-this-place-of-beauty/115510#115510) just now...!

Comment: Great write-up!

Comment: Btw #1, I am 6 was intended to refer to the letter count

Answer (score 1):

Instead of “six or thirteen” might it be “six and twelve”? If so

> Are you Florida, Delaware and Tennessee?

First:

> The two letter postal abbreviation for Florida is FL. This makes FLUFF when we add uff and is the sixth and twelfth letters of the alphabet.

Second:

> Delaware is a small east coast state. It’s name ends AWARE meaning watchful. The “West” part of its name is DEL which is short for deleted or crossed (or possibly led backwards).

Third:

> I+0 is TEN. ONE’S missing 0 is NES. I watch is SEE.

Finally:

> We are together here in our homeland: all three are part of the contiguous states of the USA.

Comment: It is 6 & 13. A correct answer will be obviously correct once you find it. There is quite a bit more to unravel (every single line), but you have one very good idea in your 'finally' notes. Good thoughts!