# Three More Adjacent Riddles ("this place of beauty")

Tags: riddle, pattern, english

*(As [before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115365/three-adjacent-riddles), the puzzle only makes sense/has a unique answer as a whole, but "easy ins" have been strategically placed.). Please explain every line rather than just the final 3 answers.*

I and no other
Hesitate briefly
As I study the arc's end
Or the curve's beginning
For you are
Desolate and unwatered, unstarted,
Hot and small, yet a place of commerce.

It is half love,
But a dash
Unlucky, reversing and cutting short
You and I,
Trapped on this place of beauty.

The sea has no beginning
For it is noble
Like art, without a
Path, half lost,
Covering this rocky place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These paragraphs clue:

> the three 'adjacent' **planets: MERCURY, VENUS and EARTH**.
>
>  In each instance the last line is a definition of sorts and the other lines each represent two consecutive characters from the name (either by definition or cryptic clue-style wordplay), which when overlapped together spell out the names we seek.

**Riddle 1:**

*I and no other*

> **ME**

*Hesitate briefly*

> **ER...**

*As I study the arc's end*

> (-a)**RC**

*Or the curve's beginning*

> **CU**(-rve)

*For you are*

> **UR**

*Desolate and unwatered, unstarted,*

> (-d)**RY**

*Hot and small, yet a place of commerce.*

> **MERCURY** is a hot but small planet. There are also various companies that go by the name of 'Mercury' (including one actually called '[Mercury Commerce](https://www.mercury-commerce.com/)'...).

**Riddle 2:**

*It is half love,*

> (-lo)**VE**

*But a dash*

> **EN** (the 'en [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)' in punctuation)

*Unlucky, reversing and cutting short*

> **NU** from UN(-lucky)<

*You and I,*

> **US**

*Trapped on this place of beauty.*

> The planet **VENUS** is named after the [Roman goddess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_(mythology)) of love and beauty.

**Riddle 3:**

*The sea has no beginning*

> (-s)**EA**

*For it is noble*

> **Ar**, the Periodic Table symbol for the *noble* gas, argon.

*Like art, without a*

> (-a)**RT**

*Path, half lost,*

> (-pa)**TH**

*Covering this rocky place.*

> **EARTH** is a rocky planet!